# How can I extract some values that fall within a range

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have about 4500 lines of aminoacid variations that look like this:

```
S1437T
H1266Y
T2662A
E1397A
E626K
S1538T
E3021K
```

Briefly, the letters flanking the numbers are the amino acid residues and the numbers represent the residue position. I would like to retrieve only those variations that fall within the range 2400 to 3100.

I tried using `grep` but wasn't so successful in doing that. Also, I know that `awk` might be better for this kind of operation but I'm a total noob when it comes to `awk`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide expected output for your example dataset please

Comment: The line `E626K` doesn't seem to fit into the scheme. Is it guaranteed that the position numbers are 4-digit, or can they be any digit length, and the only way to isolate them is to rely on there being exactly one letter before and one after the number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `perl` extracting the first sequence of digits with `\d+` and checking its value afterwards:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /\d+/ && $& >= 2400 && $& <= 3100' < your-file
T2662A
E3021K
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you for the explanation~

Comment: FWIW IMHO the code is slightly clearer when written such that the item being tested appears between the range limits, i.e. `2400 <= $& && $& <= 3100` instead of `$& >= 2400 && $& <= 3100` or similar where you have to think about what each individual condition means to be sure the test is correct overall. That applies to all the other similar answers too but commenting here since it's the accepted one and so most likely to be seen.

Answer (score 4):

Using upper-case letters as delimiters with `awk`, we can look at the second field to determine whether the line should be extracted or not:

```bsh
$ awk -F '[[:upper:]]' '$2 >= 2400 && $2 <= 3100' file
T2662A
E3021K
```

In fact, since using a field that contains a mix of digits and non-digits as a number would convert the field to a number, stopping at the first non-digit, it is enough to treat the first character on the line as a delimiter:

```bsh
$ awk -F '^.' '$2 >= 2400 && $2 <= 3100' file
T2662A
E3021K
```

---

With `sed`, it's a bit more tricky as the tool is notoriously bad at doing arithmetic.  The command below is just included as a fun distraction.

Here, we match three regular expressions against each line in the input data and print the line if there is a match.  The first expression handles the range 2400-2999, while the second expression handles the range 3000-3099.  We test 3100 separately with the third expression.  In each test, we require that one upper-case character occurs on either side of the number.

```bsh
$ sed -n \
    -e '/^[[:upper:]]2[4-9][0-9][0-9][[:upper:]]$/p' \
    -e '/^[[:upper:]]30[0-9][0-9][[:upper:]]$/p' \
    -e '/^[[:upper:]]3100[[:upper:]]$/p' file
T2662A
E3021K
```

A slightly longer editing script which more efficiently performs the tests:

```bsh
$ sed \
    -e '/^[[:upper:]]2[4-9][0-9][0-9][[:upper:]]$/b' \
    -e '/^[[:upper:]]30[0-9][0-9][[:upper:]]$/b' \
    -e '/^[[:upper:]]3100[[:upper:]]$/b' \
    -e d file
T2662A
E3021K
```

The `b` command with no argument makes the script branch to the end, where the implicit print operation outputs the current line.  The final `d` command is executed for lines that contains no match.  This ensures that lines that have matches are not tested more times than necessary.

Comment: ITYM `$2` in place of $3 in the first awk command.

Comment: @guest_7 Huh, yeah. That was weird. Thanks! Fixed now.  I did not spot it because 1) no number was greater than 3100 (so no false positive), and 2) using `$3` means evaluating a character as a number, which means testing against zero (so no false negative).

Answer (score 2):

Remove leading and trailing letters with `awk` from current row (`r`):

```
awk '{r=$0; gsub(/^[A-Z]/,"",r); gsub(/[A-Z]$/,"",r)} r>=2400 && r<=3100' file
```

Output:

```
T2662A
E3021K
```

Comment: `sub(/^[A-Z]|[A-Z]$/, "")` works just as well

Comment: @iruvar ITYM `gsub(/^[A-Z]|[A-Z]$/, "")`. In this case all you need is `gsub(/[A-Z]/,"")` though.

Comment: or with an awk which knows FPAT: `awk '$1>=2400 && $1<=3100' FPAT='[0-9]+' file`

Comment: @they: Thank you. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @EdMorton, you are right.. incidentally `sub(/^[A-Z]/, "")` works a treat on the sample data as well due to `awk` ignoring non-numeric suffixes in a numerical context

Comment: @iruvar `>=` and `<=` aren't necessarily a numerical context though, it's a numeric comparison if both of the operands are numbers or strnum (input that looks like a number) but in this case `r` is a string (it started out as `$0` not looking like a number so it was assumed to be a string and then we perform string operations, *sub()s, on it) so that would be a string comparison, not a numerical one. That actually raises the issue that this solution won't work with just `gsub(/[A-Z]/,"")` either, it needs `r+=0` or similar added before the comparison to turn `r` into a number.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks. I get what you're saying however the posted solution works in gawk 4.1.3 without the need for a `r+=0`. Possibly gawk-specific behaviour?

Comment: @iruvar I suspect you're testing with numeric parts that are all the same length or have digits in a specific order and so the string (alphabetic) comparison is producing the same output as numeric. Try `echo 'A123X' | awk '{r=$0; gsub(/[A-Z]/,"",r)} r > 70'` and  you'll see it produces no output because  the character `1` is less than the character `7` in a string/alphabetic comparison. Now try `echo 'A123X' | awk '{r=$0; gsub(/[A-Z]/,"",r); r+=0} r > 70'` and you'll see it outputs `A123X` because the number `123` is greater than the number `70`.

Comment: @EdMorton, got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne '.put if .grep(/ (<digit>+) / && {2400 <= $0 <= 3100});'
```

OR

```
raku -ne '.put if .grep(/ $<loc> = [<digit>+] / && {2400 <= $<loc> <= 3100} );'
```

Sample Input:

```
S1437T
H1266Y
T2662A
E1397A
E626K
S1538T
E3021K
```

Sample Output:

```
T2662A
E3021K
```

Briefly, Raku is called at the command line with `-ne` flags (non-autoprinting, linewise-reading). Raku's `grep` is employed to look for a match of `<digit>+` (one-or-more digits), and if found, the values are tested within a `{...}` block to see if they meet the range condition. Note how the range can be tested all in one go, with the `{2400 <= $0 <= 3100}` condition block.

The second example with `$<loc>` shows Raku's implementation of *named-captures*. See URL below for more info.

Finally, Raku offers an actual `Range` object class, so the code above can be written as follows, with a `~~` smartmatch operator and a `2400..3100` range.  Below produces the same Sample Output as above:

```
raku -ne '.put if .grep(/ $<loc> = [<digit>+] / && { $<loc> ~~ 2400..3100 } );'
```

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/Named%20captures
https://docs.raku.org/type/Range
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Python has chained comparison feature which translates closely to the intent.

```
python3 <<\eof
with open('file') as f:
  for l in f:
    n = int(l[1:-2])
    if 2400 <= n <= 3100:
      print(l,end="")
eof
T2662A
E3021K
```

Also  a range object can be made and compared against
So we can replace the chained comparison if with the following:

```
if n in range(2400,3100+1):
```

---

we can use perl's grep command to
search for existence of the number.

```
perl -lne 'my $n = s/\D//gr;
  print if grep(/^$n$/,2400..3100);
' file
```

---

Here we are using GNU sed to preprocess data for the GNU dc command which then checks for range membership by comparing the product (num-lowerlim)x(upperlim-num) >= 0 to qualify for printing.

```
sed -Ee '
  h;s/.(.*)./\1/
  x;s/.*/[&]/;G;
  s/\n/ /
' file |
dc -e "
[q]sq [p]sp
[2400-r3100r-*0!>p]su
[?z0=q dlux c z0=?]s?
l?x
"
```

---

Here in this method we first sort numeric from the 2nd column onwards

```
sort -k1.2n file |
awk '{n=0+substr($0,2)}
n < 2400 {next}
n > 3100 {exit}
1'
```